# Conditions for a function to vanish almost nowhere on its support?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $\mathrm{supp}(f) := \mathrm{cl}\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ its support.

Under which conditions is it true that $f≠0$ (Lebesgue-) almost everywhere on $\mathrm{supp}(f)$?

(I.e., under which conditions on $f$ is the set $\{x\in\mathrm{supp}(f)\mid f(x)=0\}$ necessarily a Lebesgue nullset?)

Comment: If the support is compact, this happens iff the support is Jordan measurable.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu : Thank you. (You don't happen to know how compactness of supp can be traded off against regularity conditions on f?)